# How to use If Else Statement for this android weather application

Tags: android, location, weather

When the code below runs, it shows the temperature in degrees.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
private static final String APP_ID = "80e4eede56844462ef3cdc721208c31f";

private static final int PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All good!
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Connected to Google Play Services!");

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        double lat = lastLocation.getLatitude(), lon = lastLocation.getLongitude();
        String units = "imperial";
        String url = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%f&lon=%f&units=%s&appid=%s",
                lat, lon, units, APP_ID);
        new GetWeatherTask(textView).execute(url);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Can't connect to Google Play Services!");
}

private class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TextView textView;

    public GetWeatherTask(TextView textView) {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String weather = "UNDEFINED";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputString;
            while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(inputString);
            }

            JSONObject topLevel = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");
            weather = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));


            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String temp) {
        textView.setText("Weather temperature is: " + temp + "°");


    }
}
```

}

Can someone help me on how to use the if and else statements to make it so that if the temperature is below a certain degree, the user interface will display some text and if it's above that certain degree, it will display a different text?

Comment: Please, just go google `Java if else` and `Java Android Toast` and you are good to go

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String temp) {
    textView.setText("Weather temperature is: " + temp + "°");

    if (temp < someValue)
          //doSomething
    else
        //doSomethingElse
}
```

This should be intuitive enough.

Comment: This depends on your layout. If you have a TextView, then use setText.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you will receive the temp as double value 
don't convert it to string, replace this

```
 weather = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));
```

to

```
 double weather = main.getDouble("temp");
```

and do this

```
 @Override
public void onPostExecute() {
 if (weather < yourValue)
      //yourCode 
 else
    //anthorCode
}
```

OR if you want to convert the temp value to string just add this

```
 @Override
public void onPostExecute() {
 if (weather.equals("yourValue"))
      //yourCode 
 else
    //anthorCode
}
```

and i don't recommended this.

Comment: Hi, when i added your recommendation of this:
double weather = main.getDouble("temp");

it is saying that the 'weather' is already defined in the scope. What can i do?

Comment: removeString weather;

Comment: I removed String weather = UNDEFINED and now it is saying it can't resolve the weather symbol at "return weather". How do i fix this?

Comment: more explanation please.. @JohnDoe

Comment: Yea, after i replaced  "weather = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));" with  "double weather = main.getDouble("temp");" and deleted "String weather;". 
The program is telling me that the weather symbol on "return weather" at the bottom of the code cannot be resolved. The variable "weather" in "double weather = main.getDouble.." is not in used too.

Also, I can't use the if else statement because the operator cannot be applied to a string and an int.. 

The main goal I am trying to accomplish is to just get if else statement to work but it nothing i have tried works.

Any thoughts..?

Comment: How do i go about to make it so that i can get the "temp" variable in the onPostExecute() method to be compared to a value ( ex. 65) for a if else statement? It always say operator cannot be applied to java.lang.string, int. I'm not to sure on how to make it so that the "temp" variable isn't a string.

Comment: @JohnDoe I've told you if you want to convert the temp value to string just add this
    @ Override
    public void onPostExecute(String weather) {
     if (weather.equals("yourValue"))
      //yourCode 
     else
    //anthorCode
    }
You replaced  "weather = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("temp"));" with "double weather = main.getDouble("temp");" 
and the doInBackground() returns weather as String.

Comment: Okay man it seems that you that you just copy and paste your code,
JUST Add this to your onPostExecute(String temp){
if (temp.equals("65")){
          //doSomething
}else{
          //doSomethingElse
}

Comment: Thanks. one more question, how do i do a greater than or less than comparison of temp and 65? I looked it up and i didn't quite understand.

Comment: temp is String SO You Can't do ( greater than or less than comparison ) for String Value thats why i told you to try double instead of String

Comment: Ok. I was able to find a way to get temp to be returned as a double and got the less than comparison to work. Thanks!